# How to take the value of a key in mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to mongoDB. I am using pymongo.
Here I have an example list of favorite colors stored in a mongoDB collection named `colors`:

```
mylist = [
    {"name": "Amy", "color": "Red"},
    {"name": "Hannah", "color": "Blue"},
    {"name": "Michael", "color": "Green"},
    {"name": "Sarah", "color": "Orange"}
]
```

Using the search query how do I take the value "color" using query searching using a name like Michael? So the output would be like:

```
Green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this:

Assuming that name is unique, you can try this:

```
db.colors.find_one({"name" : "Michael"})["color"]
```

You can read more about `find_one` [here](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)